# Key value in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

My output in apache beam is
(['key'],{'id':name})

Expected
('key',{'id':name})

How to do transformation using Map in apache beam to get the expected output

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets of your pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test pipeline with a lambda function that reformats your tuple using Map:

```
options = PipelineOptions()
options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

with TestPipeline(options=options) as p:
    
    bad_record = (['key'],{'id':'name'})

    records = (
        p 
        | beam.Create([bad_record])
        | beam.Map(lambda e: (e[0][0], e[1]))
        | beam.Map(print)
    )
```

The output is:

```
('key', {'id': 'name'})
```

I'm guessing that your [key] is probably being yielded instead of returned in a Map earlier in the pipeline. If you fix it there you won't need this step.